# Invalid filepath with cyrillic

Tags: java, linux

Have a test program

```
  public class Path {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("user.dir=" + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    System.out.println(Path.class.getResource(Path.class.getSimpleName() + ".class").toString());
  }
}
```

The output:

```
user.dir=/home/stas/ява
file:/home/stas/%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%b0/Path.class
```

How can i read the path to file using the second way correctly?

Comment: Well you're converting it to a URL, and that's using UTF-8-based character escaping, by the looks of it. What actual *problem* are you having?

Comment: Actual problem in this test was to get URL with cyrillic symbols. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
System.out.println(java.net.URLDecoder.decode(Path.class.getResource(Path.class.getSimpleName() + ".class").toString(), "UTF-8");
```